# What is the purpose of the upper inductor in this speaker diagram?

Tags: speakers, passive-filter

What is the upper inductor symbol in series with the woofer used for in the below diagram?

[image]

It seems the tweeter and the woofer are both I guess 8 Ohm and that's why the 4 Ohm parallel equivalent resistor is shown(?)

The CL high-pass filter for the tweeter is obvious. But I couldn't figure out the the purpose of the inductor in series with the woofer.

Comment: A low-pass filter, I would assume. A very basic one, but still a filter nonetheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I couldn't figure out the the purpose of the inductor in series
>   with the woofer.

It minimizes high frequencies into the woofer or, from the standpoint of overall load impedance presented by the filters and speakers, it's an attempt to maintain the impedance seen by the amplifier as roughly 4 ohms. As frequency rises the woofer circuit becomes progressively higher impedance and the tweeter circuit becomes progressively lower impedance.

Comment: Thanks, btw I found the exact model here https://www.radiomuseum.org/images/radio/philips_eindhoven/hi_fi_lautsprecherbox_22rh413_432129.jpg It seems like there is a capacitor but I cannot see the inductor :/(

Comment: That doesn't alter my answer.

Comment: Oh really I didnt notice that

Comment: @user164567 The photo you've linked to doesn't show any inductors at all.  Just the capacitor.  I suppose it's possible that the inductors are built into the speakers.

Comment: @SimonB I dont think so, these parts are probably manufactured separately but what do I know anyway.